# Would we benefit from a Tucker's Kobolds tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[There are 40-ish items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Tucker%27s%20Kobolds%22) that discuss tucker's Kobolds as a concept on our site. Three of them are questions. They are a beloved (and feared) meme in our community...

Would we benefit from a Tucker's Kobolds tag or should we synonymize it into some other tag, such as Action Economy?

Answer (score 11):

#### "Tucker's Kobolds" is an exceptionally specific search term, so creating a tag for it is just adding a tag tax.

There is no difficulty in finding questions and answers referencing Tucker's Kobolds because "Tucker's Kobolds" provides a specific and exhaustive search term for the subject. Creating a tag for it doesn't increase the discoverability of Tucker's Kobolds content, because just searching for it already finds everything. The only thing creating a tag for it does is add a tag tax to questions about it, so this is not a helpful tag.

Comment: It's also worth noting that most of the posts mentioning Tucker's Kobolds are answers, not questions. There's no point in having a tag if the people asking the questions don't know to use it.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I'd say this comment is almost worth a standalone answer.

Answer (score -4):

### Highly specific tags like "Tucker's Kobolds" can help

There is an benefit to having *any* tag: you can find the posts that are *concerened about* this tag, vs. those that just may mention the term tangentially. Yes, you can also use "Tucker's" as a search term, which will find everything mentioning those kobolds, but then you have to sift through 47 posts to find those that actually are about them.

There is also no limit to the number of tags that can be created so there is no real cost to it. Tagging liberally in fact is one of the flagship ways to support [The Long Tail](https://yoast.com/focus-on-long-tail-keywords/) of niche interests for discoverable content. Limiting tags to often-used ones is really defeating their purpose.

Tags even are useful if they are not comprehensive or uniform in use: even if only some questions that care about Tucker's Kobolds are tagged as such, that is already better than if none are, if you try to find this kind of post.

#### Downsides of specific tags

One limitiation is the that you can only add 5 tags to any one post, where this new tag might compete with other tags. But even for this purpose, I would prefer a more specific tag -- a tag like [monsters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters) does not really help find much of anything, as there are over 2,000 questions tagged with it, and the alternative of combining several other tags actually eats up more of that space. In the discussion about *glyph of warding*, we ended up concluding it should be [spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spell)[trap](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trap) instead, and that is not only inaccurate when you use the glyph as a spell storage device for later use, it also eats up 2 slots instead of one.

The second downside is the pyschological unease tag curators have with a grown, patchy tag landscape. There is a  desire to have tags be comprehensive and unified -- the desire is that all questions for a given tag should have it, and separate, similar tags should be merged. The reason is that nobody can keep thousands of tags in mind, so if you want to curate tags, this incentivizes the use of fewer, broader tags. Unfortunately, this also makes the resulting tags less useful for discovery.

The last downside I could think of is related to that: if you care about all posts for Tucker's Kobolds having that tag if it exists, and you add it to them, you run into the issue of potentially flooding the "front page" for a few hours until other edits push your tagging out. To be honest, I do not understand what the big problem is with flooding but I think my take on the front page is unorthodox, and there are a few active community users that care about this a lot, and that alone makes it an issue. So, the tag itself is fine, but the behaviour it could cause if combined with tagging projects could be objected to.